# Dates Appearing in Tabular Model but not appearing on Pivot table

Tags: ssas-2012, ssas-tabular

I am using SSAS tabular Model 2012, in tabular model all dates are appearing correct in date column but not when i drag attribute to my pivot table it shows only one date. Does anyone has the solution of this issue. I am using o365 Office

Dates in Tabular Model
[image: Dates in Tabular Model]

Same attribute in pivot table [image: Same attribute in pivot table]

Answer (score 0):

Ya I got the answer of my problem, the data model processing option is set to default instead of full, to deploy all the changes with data and meta data your deployment option should be set to full, not to default. for more about processing options in tabular model follow the link:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230975.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I faced the same issue in a tabular model 2019 I generated programmatically. I had a model with a simple star schema and the pivot tables from my analysis system worked for all dimensions except the time dimension, where no dates were shown in the pivot table.

I found out that there was a mismatch between the actual data type (DateTime) and the data type I used to create the relationships in my star schema programmatically (that in my case defaulted to String, even for the time dimension). The tabular model did not create any warnings and even processed smoothly without any errors, so the error was quite hard to discover.